# Maven/Eclipse plugin: easiest way to have new Maven project have dependency on legacy non-Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a new Maven project in Eclipse.  This was working fine until I needed to add a dependency to another Eclipse project, a legacy utility project, which does not have a pom.xml, and does not have the directory structure of a typical Maven project. (It has the directory structure of a typical eclipse Java project).  This other project is in the same Eclipse workspace as the Maven project.

In looking at other posts on this, it seems that usually the solution is to build the jar for the other project and install it in Maven.  However I am actively modifying code in the utility project while writing code in the Maven project, so I can't just install a jar once to satisfy the dependency.

What is the easiest way to handle this so that I can code simultaneously in both projects, and also get maven to build cleanly?  (Of course Eclipse can build just fine with just a project dependency.)

**UPDATE**

Using the Build Helper plugin to add the utility projects source folder to my pom was a viable path to the solution, but then I needed to update all the dependencies of the utility project into my new Mavne project, which started to make the whole process too time consuming (and also not really the chain of dependencies I wanted). I think that if I would have added all the dependencies, then Build Helper suggestion would have worked.

For now, I built the utility project jar and installed it into maven. Which turned out to be the the quickest solution.  I will try to Mavenize the utility project, without modifying its structure (as suggested by FrVaBe below), and see if I can link the poms afterward.

I am going to keep this question open until I have a full solution which can be reported back, since I assume this is a problem others will have (trying to integrate legacy projects with new maven projects).

Answer (score 3):

For the development time you can add the dependency as a [System Dependency](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies). It will be resolved by the file path (which can be the path to your utility.jar file under development) in this case.

It is added as describe in the link above, e.g.:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my-utility</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-utility</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${somewhere}/lib/my-utility.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The maven handling of System dependencies is sometimes special. E.g. they will not be included in war-packages! Therefore, when you are finished I would strongly recommend to install your utility library to the maven respository or to deploy it to a repository manager (Nexus/Artifactory).

Comment: I'm very new to Maven - could you please explain how to add System dependency?

Comment: I tried to add a system dependency, setting `<systemPath>` to the root folder of the class files. However it seems Maven wants that path to be to a jar file, and not a folder.

Comment: @SamGoldberg Yes, it has to be your utility jar file. If you want to add different source/resource directories you can try the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) but I would not use this project overlapping.

Comment: I took a quick look at build-helper-maven-plugin and it may solve the problem, but there was barely any documentation (and my eclipse plugin search feature is inconsistent so the Maven -> add plugin didn't find it).  I will look into this later (I hope), but didn't seem like a quick solution.  (i.e more fumbling on my part to get it referenced correctly, and then testing if it actually works for my scenario).

Comment: @SamGoldberg If you spend too much time to setup your (probably poor) workaround better think of mavenizing your utility project. You can do this without changing to the standard maven directory layout (although this would be recommended) by mostly just overriding the definitions of the [Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM).

Answer (score 1):

You can add utility project's src folder to your working project in eclipse. For your development purpose.

```
right click on Working project
go to properties and choose java build path
go to source tab
Add your utility project src folder to that.
```

Later you can install your jar as maven dependency.

Comment: This is already done. But I when I tried to do: `mvn test` to make sure everything was working, it failed, because it didn't resolve the Eclipse project dependency. I am trying to find a way that I can set it up to build both from `mvn` command, and also within Eclipse.